# AngularJS $route gives error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS, and trying to use `$route` to show different views but getting error in my console. Here is my code:

*index.html*

```
<!Doctype html>
<html ng-app="approute">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" href="">
        <title>Search The Angles: {{people.name}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" ng-model="test">{{test | json}}

        <div ng-view></div>

        <a href="#/path2">Html2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my script is as follows:

```
'use strict';

var approute = angular.module("approute", ['ngRoute']);

approute.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/path2', {
            templateUrl: "partials/index2.html",
            controller: "appCountroller"
        })
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "partials/index1.html",
            controller: "appCountroller"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);

approute.controller("appCountroller", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('../json/data.json').success(function(response) {
        $scope.people = response;
    });
});
```

*index1* and *index2.html* are in following format:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:test">{{person.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and *index2.html*

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:test">{{person.name}}-{{person.position}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I tried  opening in a browser, I get the following error on my console:

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
>       at Error (native)...

with reference to my *angular.min.js* file

I've checked everything I could, but not seeing what's causing the error.

Comment: can you update a plunker for this? This should work

Comment: from your error, you are using angular 1.2.27. May be error is coming because you are using different version of angular.route. Can you confirm? btw [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sGYLfNS5H1H3yFBRUcYB?p=preview) is working example of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that dependencies cannot be resolve. In this case it  look like it's about templateRequestProvider in ng-route.

Check that the version of angular-route and the version of angular are not conflicting, I think it might be that.